# XSLT- Changing XML format and reusability

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xslt

I could use some assistance with my XML transformation, I've viewed other similar questions but since my XML schema is a little awkward I'm having trouble applying it.

Here is the XML format I have

```
<root>
  <row>
  <var name="Name" value="Rusell" />
  <var name=" Surname" value=" Anthony" />
  <var name=" Country" value=" UK" />
  <var name=" Job" value="Web Designer" />
  <var name=" Cabin" value="345" />
 </row>
  <row>
  <var name="Name" value="Wolf" />
  <var name=" Surname" value=" Werner" />
  <var name=" Country" value=" Germany" />
  <var name=" Job" value="Linux IT" />
  <var name=" Cabin" value="234" />
 </row>
</root>
```

And this is what I want it to look like so I can access fields easily.

```
<root>
 <row name="Rusell" surName="Anthony" country="UK" job="Web Designer" cabin="345" />
 <row name="Wolf" surname="Werner" country="Germany" job="Linux IT" cabin="234" />
</row>
```

I have made progress as far as the formatting goes this is what I have got so far- The values have not been inserted.

```
<root>
<row Name="" Surname="" Country="" Job="" Cabin="" />
<row Name="" Surname="" Country="" Job="" Cabin="" />
<row Name="" Surname="" Country="" Job="" Cabin="" />
<row Name="" Surname="" Country="" Job="" Cabin="" />
</root>
```

Here is my XSLT file -
You will notice for a couple of the attributes, when using value-of select I have different syntax this is just to show what I have tried.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
<xsl:apply-templates/>

</root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">

<row>
<xsl:attribute name="Name">
<xsl:value-of select="value"/>

</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="Surname">
<xsl:value-of select="row/root/name/value"/>

</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="Country">
<xsl:value-of select="root/row/value"/>

</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="Job">
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>

</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="Cabin">
<xsl:value-of select="value"/>

</xsl:attribute>

</row>

</xsl:template>
```

Also, about the re usability issue, the above method is fine when I know the fields and attributes but I will be taking in different XML files with possibly more fields i.e address,age.

So how would I go about creating an XSLT file that does the following;

```
For each Node = root/row
Create row = (value@name & value@value)
```

I.E the same as what I'm trying to do above but reusable as in I don't need to know the name values (surname,cabin etc) so its applicable to my first XML file and the following.

```
<root>
  <row>
  <var name="differentName" value="x" />
  <var name="anotherdifferentname" value="y" />
 </row>
  </root>
```

If I need to be clearer please let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: You've been given an answer, but sometimes I feel it's more important to tell people what they did wrong. Basically your paths are all over the place, they look like wild guesswork. In a template that matches row, the path to Anthony is `var[@name='Surname']/@value` - that is, select the child 'var' element whose 'name' attribute equals 'Surname', and then select the 'value' attribute of this 'var' element.

Comment: Yes I appreciate your criticism, I am clueless with XSL which is probably obvious to you. thanks for explaining the syntax

Comment: @Michael Kay - It would be nice if you made your comment an answer so we can vote on it (yes I know the OP has accepted another, but your solution is more appropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="var"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="var">
    <xsl:variable name="attributeName" select="@name">
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="{$attributeName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great I haven't tested this yet I will shortly, but you have laid out the syntax for me regardless thanks a lot